# How to search through my database and how to store there parsed data on python

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql

I'm working on creating parser for linkedin profiles to store database of candidates resume for my Diploma project. I decided to make it as Web app so I'm using django at this point and I have little plan:

1. Use API of linkedin to get info in JSON form
2. Store it in Postgres
3. Create a search on Site which can be used by multiple connections at the same time and can be updated.

But there I have some problems:

I don't know what i should do to store this info. I understand that i have some data like this in form of json.

```
    [
 {'categories': ['Web Development',
                  'Software Development',
                  'Writing & Translation'],
  'country': 'India',
  'description': 'I do ...',
  'feedback': '4.8424790960452',
  'id': '~aaaa9999d3f394624e',
  'last_activity': 'June 17, 2014',
  'member_since': 'July 21, 2011',
  'name': 'John Johnson',
  'portfolio_items_count': '1',
  'portrait_50': 'https://...',
  'profile_type': 'Independent',
  'rate': '22.22',
  'skills': ['python',
              'django-framework',
              'mongodb',
              'jquery',
              'html5',
              'postgresql'],
 'test_passed_count': '3',
 'title': 'Web Developer'},
 {
   # Another freelancer
 },
 # ...
]
```

But I can't understand what I should do to create tables and put this info into them. So if you provide me example it's will be nice.

The second problem is that I don't get at all how I can search the info I needed. For example i need to search "Programmer" and I want to get all the data where this word appear or relative. For example "I used to be a programmer, but now I'm working as Project Manager" or "I have skills in programming with PHP". For me it's simple like I just use search for a word in a string ofc to search for relatives I need to short my word to lemma, but I guess it's not like I imagine it.

And also I guess to be able to update my database i should use AJAX + JQuery, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If using Django, create a model based on the format of the JSON from
   linkedin, if not, create the table manually via Postgres.
2. Create script to pull all data from linkedin API and store it in your Postgres DB.
3. Use Django ORM or raw SQL to preform LIKE queries on the free text you are searching for in Postgres.  Preferably, load a search engine such as ElasticSearch with all of your data so that you could do tokenized searches which return relative values against free text searches.

Answer (score 0):

I think more recent versions of postgres have a JSON datatype, but I'm not sure if django supports querying it, def something to look up.

Normally integrating with a data source requires you to evaluate what sort of data you have (the json you posted)

How you are going to store your data,

How you are going to extract and transform the data from the data feed to import into your system

And actually importing it

---

Looking at the feed a couple of things stand out.

a `Profile` model with m2m to a `Skill`s models and a m2m with a `Category` model

This should allow you easy quick lookup of any profiles given a specific category or skill

---

The django tutorial provides extremely well written examples on how to create models, interact with models, persist data using models and how to query models.